# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to integrate Jetpack Compose in my project with Android Studio 4.2 and I am getting the following error in the IDE:

> Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings

I also checked the settings below:

- Android gradle plugin version: 4.2.0-alpha01
- Gradle version: 6.5-rc-1

**app/build.gradle:**

```
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.70-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200424"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev13"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The IDE seems to use a value defined in the `.idea/gradle.xml` file in your project.

If in that file, you have something like the following:

```
<option name="gradleJvm" value="12.0.1" />
```

try **replacing it with that** instead:

```
<option name="gradleJvm" value="1.8" />
```

**EDIT:** [This was a bug in Android Studio 4.1 canary/beta that got fixed in 4.1 beta 2.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156112443)

Comment: There is no **gradleJvm** field in `gradle.xml` file.

Comment: Then your issue is probably different @IgorGanapolsky.

Comment: You can also just delete the line ** <option name="gradleJvm" value="12.0.1" /> ** from the file ".idea/gradle.xml" to help it to **Use JDK from project structure** automatically.

Answer (score 105):

I got this issue in `Android studio 4.2 canary`, and I had to delete those generated files:

- .idea/gradle.xml
- .idea/workspace.xml

then clicking try again to sync the project.

Comment: Just got this on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 4. This solution worked.

Comment: I have to do this whenever it makes me redownload the entire Studio software from their site to update, like 4.2, instead of just a patch.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim It worked for me too. Thanks a lot. Up-voted the answer.

Comment: I believe you only need to delete `gradle.xml`, deleting `workspace.xml` is not advisable if you have running configurations

Comment: Same problem with Android Studio 4.2.1
Your solution worked!

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same issue but for Android Studio Version 4.1.2
I tried below step and it worked as a charm for me.

1. Delete the .idea folder from the File Explorer/Finder.
2. Open **Files -> Settings -> Gradle**.
3. Change Gradle user Home to Project_Path/.gradle (D:/Work/Project/.gradle) and apply it.
4. Sync the project